# OpenSSH Won't Authenticate with Keypair

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

**Problem**

When I try configuring key pair authentication to OpenSSH-Server running on Ubuntu, I am still prompted for a password.

I've generated key pairs with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and did not set a key passphrase.  Then, I copied the public key (renamed to JNNIntelNUC) to the Ubuntu server using `ssh-copy-id -i <private key file> username@192.168.100.222`.  All seemed to go well, and I can see the public key contents in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

I then try to establish a connection from the client using `ssh -i <private key file> username@192.168.100.222` but am still prompted for a password.

Any ideas?

**What I've Checked**

- I've uninstalled OpenSSH-Server, removed all config files, and did a clean install
- I've checked file and folder permissions.  Debug messages don't indicate a permission issue.
- I tried generating ed25519 keys instead of rsa keys, and nothing changed
- I checked the sshd_config file on the server.  It defaults with `PubkeyAuthentication yes` and `AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys`.  I've even tried over-riding them with identical manual settings.

**Debug Output**

Here's the output that's relevant of `ssh -I <private key file> usenrame@192.168.100.222 -v`

```
debug1: Will attempt key: JNNIntelNUC ED25519 SHA256:CiXH3VTQ5ZWyFOwJe2nfffbwY+/cv8OWICj5iDQ5pKs explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
```

Comment: Can you post sshd_config for the server?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I found the issue, and it wasn't related to sshd_config (from what I can tell, the sshd_config default configuration should work fine).

Answer (score 1):

Sigh, it was indeed a permission issue.  I expected the ssh command with the -v flag to state it was a permission issue, but it didn't.  The issue was the permissions on the home user's directory on the server.

```
chmod go-w /home/*username* #<-- This is the one I was missing
chmod 700 /home/*username*/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/*username*/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I was able to find the error message by checking the log files for the SSH daemon using `grep 'sshd' /var/log/auth.log`

Comment: The client cannot know that you have wrong permissions on the server.

Comment: I would not expect using `-v` on the client to tell you about a permission problem on the server, because it'd be generally a bad idea for a server to tell an unauthenticated (at that point) client about its security problems. That'd make it easier for any potential attackers to probe the server for weaknesses.

Comment: Martin, Gordon, thanks for your reply and makes total sense.  The server’s response about which algorithms were supported had me chasing my tail thinking it was a key algorithm issue, a bit of a red herring.  Now I know to interpret that response as “there’s an unknown issue with the server.”